# PostgreSQL: format timestamp with T delimiter between time and date

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

What I expect:

```
SELECT to_char(current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24-MI-SS')
```

to produce:

```
2022-11-11T11-29-51
```

But it produces:
[image]

I've tried several options, but neither of them does the trick:
[image]
Query for convenience:

```
SELECT to_char(current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24-MI-SS') as plain,
       to_char(current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', E'YYYY-MM-DD\'T\'HH24-MI-SS') as with_quotes,
       to_char(current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD\THH24-MI-SS') as with_backslash,
       to_char(current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DDT HH24-MI-SS') as with_space
```

It looks like that T letter gets parsed as part of pattern and then got skipped in a plain sample.
Any idea how to get desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes to escape a constant values:

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

> Ordinary text is allowed in to_char templates and will be output literally. You can put a substring in double quotes to force it to be interpreted as literal text even if it contains template patterns. For example, in `'"Hello Year "YYYY'`, the `YYYY` will be replaced by the year data, but the single Y in Year will not be

```
to_char(current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24-MI-SS')
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Silly me not trying this option.